# Is using the rename database feature in PHPMyAdmin safe?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, alter-database

I know the rename database functionality has been taken out of MySQL. My question is, does renaming it in PHPMyAdmin work and is safe? I know they have written functionality to deal with a number of issues that can arise but I haven't found any commentary on whether it's safe.

By safe I mean no data/structure loss.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643802/rename-mysql-database) , there might be data loss. The same is confirmed via [MySQL official document](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-5.1-relnotes-en.a4.pdf) here. Please correct me if something is missing from my point of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* the problem with `RENAME DATABASE` was that there was no practical way to lock everything sufficiently to keep other connections from accidentally "causing data loss".  So, I *suspect* MySQL chose to remove the feature rather than live with the complaints.

Keep in mind that triggers, events, stored procedures, stored functions, cross-db operations (eg `FROM db1.tbl1 JOIN db2.tbl2`), etc *could* cause trouble.

With that in mind, if you are doing *nothing* else in the database (as in 'you are the only user'), then the following *may* be 'safe':

It *may* be that phpmyadmin simulates the operation by creating the new database, renaming each table, etc.

(Version 8.0 *may* reinstate it because the "Data Dictionary" can do DDL in a transactional manner.)

Feel free to add a comment to http://bugs.mysql.com/86289 .  Or at least click on "Affects me".